# Firebase functions not deploying when uses functions.database.ref

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm in problem because I can't deploy my firebase functions if I add a new function with functions.database.

I have followed the first example step by step, but I think exists any trouble with the new version of firebase-tools.

This is de url of the "get started" https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0

The first step works for me:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   // Grab the text parameter.
   const original = req.query.text;
   // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
   return admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then((snapshot) => {
   // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
   return res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
 });
```

This code is possible to deploy, but when I add the next code to upper the string saved...appears this error:

firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'test-app'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

The bug code:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages').onWrite((change, context) => {

  const original = event.before.val();
   const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();

  return change.data.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set("uppercase");
})
```

I installed via npm locally  a lot of times, in different folder and projects, but always the same

This is my package.json inside /functions

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^1.2.0",
    "stripe": "^5.8.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49699813/4815718.  Recommend solution there is to update `firebase-tools`:  `npm i -g firebase-tools@latest`

Comment: Same error, sorry but I have tried all possible installations...

Comment: Also, I try with another version of node, but occurs the same

Comment: Maybe not related to the error you are seeing, but the code is invalid.  There is no longer an `event`.  [See changes doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0#realtime-database).  Should be `const original = change.before.val()`